# Makefile not set GOOS environment variable

Tags: windows, go, makefile, cross-compiling

I write below Makefile to build Golang code for different platforms. (My OS is Windows 10 and run Makefile through command prompt)

```
GOCMD   =  go
GOBUILD =  $(GOCMD)  build
GOFILES =   $(wildcard *.go)
SONG_PATH =  ./song-service
SONG_PATH_OUTPOUT =  ./song-service/cmd
SONG_BINARY_NAME_LIN =  songservice_lin

song-build-lin:
    set GOOS=linux
    set GOARCH=amd64
    $(GOBUILD)  -o "$(SONG_PATH_OUTPOUT)/$(SONG_BINARY_NAME_LIN)" -v "$(SONG_PATH)/$(GOFILES)"
```

When I run `make song-build-lin` it runs without error but GOOS variable doesn't set.
But when I run `set GOOS=linux` in command prompt directly it works!

Comment: Every command in `song-build-lin` is executing in a separate subshell. Add a semincolon `;` and a backslash `\\` after each line to group the execution in one subshell

Comment: I changed commands to `set GOOS=linux;\   set GOARCH=amd64;\ `but still not working!

Comment: If you're using msys/make then your SHELL is /bin/sh. It has different syntax for assigning environment variables. I.e. remove "set".

Comment: Or use `env`, e.g. `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD)...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer finally,

I run make command using VSCode terminal, the terminal type that I used, was Command Prompt. If you change the terminal type to Git bash, commands work correctly.

Comment: I run command set GOOS=linux using git bash but it not works,
i found another answer to do this run command on your command promt
go env -w GOOS=linux
its work for me

Answer (score 1):

This is a great questions, and a great thread.
I am forced to use Windows for work purposes for development.  I have a few teammates that use Windows, and a few that use Mac, and a couple people that would prefer to work on Linux but are unable to, and we just got some Linux servers that we need to compile an executable to.  I recently came across the Makefile Tutorial website [https://makefiletutorial.com/](https://makefiletutorial.com/#makefile-cookbook), and they had a section on exporting variables.
On my windows machine I was able to use a shell, cygwin.
Below is the compile in the make file that I was able to use...

```
# compile - cross compile all platforms
compile:
    @echo " === Compiling for every OS and Platform === "
    make compile-linux
    make compile-win 
    make compile-mac
    @echo " === COMPLETED! === "

# compile-linux - compile and create a linux executable for 64bit architecture
# NOTE: this sets the GOOS and GOARCH just for this makefile rule
compile-linux: export GOOS=linux
compile-linux: export GOARCH=amd64
compile-linux:
    go build -o bin/executable-linux.exe

# compile-win - compile and create a windows executable for 64bit architecture 
compile-win: export GOOS=windows
compile-win: export GOARCH=amd64
compile-win:
    go build -o bin/executable-win.exe

# compile-mac - compile and create a mac os executable for 64bit architecture 
compile-mac: export GOOS=darwin
compile-mac: export GOARCH=amd64
compile-mac:
    go build -o bin/executable-mac
```

This seems to work for me, with Powershell 7 and/or Windows Command Line, as well as my teammates who are using MacOS.
This is generic, and can be added used just about anywhere.

For this solution (although its already been answered for 2+ years) might be something like this...

```
GOCMD   =  go
GOBUILD =  $(GOCMD)  build
GOFILES =   $(wildcard *.go)
SONG_PATH =  ./song-service
SONG_PATH_OUTPOUT =  ./song-service/cmd
SONG_BINARY_NAME_LIN =  songservice_lin

song-build-lin: export GOOS=linux
song-build-lin: export GOARCH=amd64
song-build-lin:
    $(GOBUILD)  -o "$(SONG_PATH_OUTPOUT)/$(SONG_BINARY_NAME_LIN)" -v "$(SONG_PATH)/$(GOFILES)"
```

I would love to know if this works for you and for others, and if there is any other improvements to this.  I am not a huge Makefile person, I would love to learn and improve on this.